# Overfilled the engine oil. Drained everything. Is it ok to refill?

Tags: engine, oil

Like an idiot, I drained the transmission fluid and not the oil. I then over filled the oil by about 4 quarts. Luckily, I caught this and did not start the engine. I then drained all the oil that was in the engine, really letting it drain for about an hour. I have replaced the trans fluid, and am going to fill the oil to the appropriate level and then start it. Is there something I should do before starting it or even refilling the oil?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! T

Answer (score 2):

Nope. Shouldn't be an issue. Just make sure all fluids are up to snuff and you're good to go.

Comment: If one must make an overfill error, this OP did a great job of recovery!

Comment: @fred_dot_u - Absolutely! :o)